# can I make the panel width the width of the image inside the coda slider?

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I am making a site using coda slider, the panelWidth I'd like to be set depending on the image width in the div.

```
$(".panel").each(function(){
                        var imageWidth = $(this).find("img").width()+1;
                        $(this).width(imageWidth);

                    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/Fqupf/

Comment: @YNhat The code works, but not in combination with the coda slider jQuery-Plugin. This uses a width for the clip-area of the stage...

Comment: I feel I'm nearly there, just need to sort the "clip-area" of the stage. so to speak..

Answer (score 0):

One way for your problem is to modify the coda slider plugin. I didn't find a out of the box way to do this with the plugin. Here is a rough way to do what you want, look at it as a little inspiration. I modified the `alterPanelHeight` function, so if you set the `autoHeight` option, it will alter the width, too. Note: The modification will not alter the width on load, the first modification will take place after the first scroll...

```
    function alterPanelHeight(x) {
        if (settings.autoHeight) {
            newSliderWidth = $('.panel:eq('+x+')').find('img').width();
            panelHeight = $('.panel:eq(' + x + ')', slider).height()
            slider.animate({ height: panelHeight, width: newSliderWidth }, settings.autoHeightEaseDuration, settings.autoHeightEaseFunction);

        };
    };
```

Comment: Hmm i added a similar function alterPanelWidth and got nothing, might need to console to see what the issue is, has no one tried this?